# javascript modal window for forms

Tags: javascript, modal-window

Do you know of a nice javascript library that will allow me to create modal windows specifically for forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, using mootools:

http://digitarald.de/project/squeezebox/

http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/lightface.php

Answer (score 3):

You may take a look at [those plugins](http://elijahmanor.com/webdevdotnet/post/Top-5-jQuery-Modal-Plugins.aspx) if you are using jquery. [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) is very good.

Answer (score 1):

may be thickbox is ok

thickbox:http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Answer (score 0):

I made [this library](https://madprops.github.io/Msg/) that enables you to make a modal window easily. You can put any html inside of it.